# Lists, Dict and Lists of Dict - CS50 and Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is for the CS50 course an assignment called DNA in python, Ive struggled for days researching and trying to work out how to get the final section to work. I'm a newbie.

I've uploaded a database of people and their DNA into memory into a list of dict's.

I've then read a test sample of DNA into memory as a string and then searched and filtered it looking for DNA sequences.

So what I now have is a dict called str_test AND the list of dict's called data holding everyone's DNA, I need to somehow compare str_test  with data to see if anyone matched and return the persons name.

Like I said I'm struggling with this, I have worked out how to loop and address the values in  data - the list of dict and also str_test the dict of results but I can't blend them together.

I apologies for the amount of #d out areas but they are for me for testing, any guidance would be appreciated. The last 5 to 7 lines are me trying to loop through but that's wrong there has to be a simple better way, thanks

```
import csv
import sys

def main():

    # Ensure correct usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")

    data = []

    with open(sys.argv[1], "r")  as csvfile:                     #open the file in the command line argument
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for row in reader:  #lets go loopy
            row = (row)
            data.append(row)

            #print(row)
            #print(data)
            #print(reader.fieldnames)
            #print(data)

    with open(sys.argv[2], "r")  as file:  #open the sample file in the command line argument

        sequence = file.read()  #read it to array/memory

        print(reader.fieldnames)  #test print
        print(sequence)  #test print

#two files now opened
#sequence is the test DNA sequence


#we want to loop through the STR's here and take the first and then loop that through the sequence


    str_test = {}           # a dictionary for the counts

    for i in range (1, (len(reader.fieldnames ))):  #read the header field names ie STR, count them starting after name field
        sample = (reader.fieldnames[i])
        print(reader.fieldnames)
        print(sample)  #DNA type to compare to test string called SEQUENCE
        str_test[sample] = 0

        for j in range(len(sequence)):  # this will loop through the long string to be tested for the STR DNA (sample)

            step = 0
            max_count = 0

            while sequence[j + step:j+step+len(sample)]  == sample:
                step = step + len(sample)
                max_count += 1
                print(max_count)

            j = j + step
                                                                #test = (str_test.get(sample))
            if max_count > (str_test.get(sample)):  #get the existing value of the sample and compare
                str_test[sample] = max_count  #if count is larger then update field if not continue


    print(str_test)  #test print to see whats in the dictionary
    print(str_test.values())
    #print(key.values())
    #print(data)
    #print(len(data))
    #print(type(str_test))


    for d in data:  #data is a list of dictionaries - so this is cycle through the list  [1:] to start at first
        for values in (str_test):  #start to loop through the dictionary for the test string dna results

            for key in d:  #this is cycling through the dictionary  thats part of the list of dictionaries

                strvalue = str_test.get(values)
                datavalue = int(d.get(values)

main()
```

the information contained in str_test looks like this -

```
{'AGATC': 4, 'TTTTTTCT': 0, 'AATG': 1, 'TCTAG': 0, 'GATA': 1, 'TATC': 5, 'GAAA': 1, 'TCTG': 0}
```

the information in the list of dict Ive got to search for a match against the str_test above looks like this:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'Albus',
    'AGATC': '15',
    'TTTTTTCT': '49',
    'AATG': '38',
    'TCTAG': '5',
    'GATA': '14',
    'TATC': '44',
    'GAAA': '14',
    'TCTG': '12'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Cedric',
    'AGATC': '31',
    'TTTTTTCT': '21',
    'AATG': '41',
    'TCTAG': '28',
    'GATA': '30',
    'TATC': '9',
    'GAAA': '36',
    'TCTG': '44'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Draco',
    'AGATC': '9',
    'TTTTTTCT': '13',
    'AATG': '8',
    'TCTAG': '26',
    'GATA': '15',
    'TATC': '25',
    'GAAA': '41',
    'TCTG': '39'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Fred',
    'AGATC': '37',
    'TTTTTTCT': '40',
    'AATG': '10',
    'TCTAG': '6',
    'GATA': '5',
    'TATC': '10',
    'GAAA': '28',
    'TCTG': '8'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Ginny',
    'AGATC': '37',
    'TTTTTTCT': '47',
    'AATG': '10',
    'TCTAG': '23',
    'GATA': '5',
    'TATC': '48',
    'GAAA': '28',
    'TCTG': '23'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Hagrid',
    'AGATC': '25',
    'TTTTTTCT': '38',
    'AATG': '45',
    ... # this is a short extract
```

Comment: Just a couple of quick notes.  `sys.exit` does not print its results.  It accepts an integer that gets returned as a return code.  Use `print` there.  Second, `row = (row)` does absolutely nothing.  You don't need it anyway.

Comment: So, you know how to do a loop.  `for row in data:` / `if sequence in row['dna']:` seems to be what you need.  You didn't show us the data, so we don't know what the columns are.

Comment: {'AGATC': 4, 'TTTTTTCT': 0, 'AATG': 1, 'TCTAG': 0, 'GATA': 1, 'TATC': 5, 'GAAA': 1, 'TCTG': 0} is the string ive filtered and need to match,  the listofdict is [{'name': 'Albus', 'AGATC': '15', 'TTTTTTCT': '49', 'AATG': '38', 'TCTAG': '5', 'GATA': '14', 'TATC': '44', 'GAAA': '14', 'TCTG': '12'}, {'name': 'Cedric', 'AGATC': '31', 'TTTTTTCT': '21', 'AATG': '41', 'TCTAG': '28', 'GATA': '30', 'TATC': '9', 'GAAA': '36', 'TCTG etc, thats a small extract but will give u the idea, thankyou for any advice, C was logical Python confused me addressing locations, thanks

Comment: Im just looking at the if sequence in row, I think I need....  if str_test  in row['data'} for the command, still trying to work this syntax out, my data file has the dict key in it 'name' where the test file doesn't its just straight keys:values , how does that effect the if sequence in row?, thanks Tim

Comment: you could add example data directly in code assigned to variables (instead of reading from files) so we could simply copy and run it to see problems and test solutions on this code.

Comment: Given your data, your description of the problem makes no sense at all.  Every name in your list contains every sequence in your search list.  I can show you an answer, but there must be more to the problem than what you've shared.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you asked, but I'm 100% certain what you asked is not the problem you were asked to solve.  As I mentioned, every name in your name list contains every sequence in your search list.  It's pretty easy to process, because the keys in your database are the exact sequences, so you don't even have to do string searches.

```
searches = {'AGATC': 4, 'TTTTTTCT': 0, 'AATG': 1, 'TCTAG': 0, 'GATA': 1, 'TATC': 5, 'GAAA': 1, 'TCTG': 0}

database = [
    {'name': 'Albus', 'AGATC': '15', 'TTTTTTCT': '49', 'AATG': '38', 'TCTAG': '5', 'GATA': '14', 'TATC': '44', 'GAAA': '14', 'TCTG': '12'}, 
    {'name': 'Cedric', 'AGATC': '31', 'TTTTTTCT': '21', 'AATG': '41', 'TCTAG': '28', 'GATA': '30', 'TATC': '9', 'GAAA': '36', 'TCTG': '44'}, 
    {'name': 'Draco', 'AGATC': '9', 'TTTTTTCT': '13', 'AATG': '8', 'TCTAG': '26', 'GATA': '15', 'TATC': '25', 'GAAA': '41', 'TCTG': '39'}, 
    {'name': 'Fred', 'AGATC': '37', 'TTTTTTCT': '40', 'AATG': '10', 'TCTAG': '6', 'GATA': '5', 'TATC': '10', 'GAAA': '28', 'TCTG': '8'}, 
    {'name': 'Ginny', 'AGATC': '37', 'TTTTTTCT': '47', 'AATG': '10', 'TCTAG': '23', 'GATA': '5', 'TATC': '48', 'GAAA': '28', 'TCTG': '23'}, 
    {'name': 'Hagrid', 'AGATC': '25', 'TTTTTTCT': '38', 'AATG': '45'}]

for row in database:
    for search in searches.keys():
        if  search in row:
            print( row['name'], 'matches', search )
```

Output:

```
Albus matches AGATC
Albus matches TTTTTTCT
Albus matches AATG
Albus matches TCTAG
Albus matches GATA
Albus matches TATC
Albus matches GAAA
Albus matches TCTG
Cedric matches AGATC
Cedric matches TTTTTTCT
Cedric matches AATG
Cedric matches TCTAG
Cedric matches GATA
Cedric matches TATC
Cedric matches GAAA
Cedric matches TCTG
Draco matches AGATC
Draco matches TTTTTTCT
Draco matches AATG
Draco matches TCTAG
Draco matches GATA
Draco matches TATC
Draco matches GAAA
Draco matches TCTG
Fred matches AGATC
Fred matches TTTTTTCT
Fred matches AATG
Fred matches TCTAG
Fred matches GATA
Fred matches TATC
Fred matches GAAA
Fred matches TCTG
Ginny matches AGATC
Ginny matches TTTTTTCT
Ginny matches AATG
Ginny matches TCTAG
Ginny matches GATA
Ginny matches TATC
Ginny matches GAAA
Ginny matches TCTG
Hagrid matches AGATC
Hagrid matches TTTTTTCT
Hagrid matches AATG
```

Comment: sorted, thanks for the advice, you got me looking at the data structures a little different and how I searched them, thankyou